# Set time between Animation

Tags: android, animation

In android we are using`setDuration(long) used set amount of time for the animation to run. If there is any method to control time in between the animation ?

Answer (score 1):

If the animations are defined in XML you can use the start offset:

```
android:startOffset="500"
```

You can also use the method [setStartOffset(long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setStartOffset(long)) on any animation in the code.

As proposed by Chaosit Animators are a good way to go when doing animations, Vogella got a good introductions Animators [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidAnimation/article.html). By using [setStartDelay(long startDelay)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html#setStartDelay(long)) and using [AnimatorListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener.html) you can delay the animation and start new animations when needed.

Comment: But yeah, I would suggest using of Animators instead of Animations, they are far more comfortable to use